# Meta of Meta: What Should We Accept As "Accepted Answers" of Feature Requests?

Tags: discussion, tags, accepted-answer, meta

*This is a question about how Meta works, and it does not directly pertain to the other SO sites.*

In the [feature-request] tag here on Meta, for questions which make some sort of request, what answers should we "accept"? It is not clear per the current analogy of accepting answers.

Should we accept ones where a person from the Stack Overflow team answers, as this is changing the status of the feature-request? However, not all feature-requests are touched by the team. Or, should we just accept the ones we (and the community) feels would be the best approach towards this request?

Comment: A meta-meta site would be interesting. But then someone would want to see a meta-meta-meta site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a feature request, if Jeff responds with an answer then I accept his answer after the feature is done (or at least after *I* think it's done!). Otherwise, I treat it as discussion and don't bother.

This is meta, the usual accept game doesn't apply here.